# Создание полноценного процесса в mono

Tags: c#, .net, mono, monodevelop

Нужно сделать процесс для Ubuntu в Mono, который мониторит определенный порт на предмет входящих подключений и потом их обрабатывает. Нужна возможность поддерживать такие команды:

```
service <MyProgramName> start
service <MyProgramName> stop
service <MyProgramName> restart
service <MyProgramName> info
service <MyProgramName> statistics
```

Все что нашел, это запуск чего-то подобного но с помощью скриптов на bash. Есть ли способ обрабатывать данные команды в Mono?